# Other Data on Apple - How do I clean cache and other unused data on Mac

Tags: macos, catalina, data

How do I clean cache and other unused data on Mac?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should not need to 'clean' caches. You will not recover much space, and the OS will immediately try to re-populate the caches, so the space will be filled again.

Apple's utility for Managing Storage is not always accurate in its categories (nor is the Storage display in **About This Mac**).

Usually, most stuff on your storage is yours. User data. Stuff you've created or downloaded. Click on **File Browser** on that window you've shown. That will give you a list of things on your disk, sorted by size. Then you can see what's taking the most space.

Comment: added another image, how can I check what is there in the others folder?

Comment: Looks like Apple's Browser only shows the User domain. Use an app like OmniDiskSweeper (free download) to browse your whole disk, sorted by size. Clearly, you've got something very large outside your user area.